# Make routing to my custom module in magento

Tags: php, magento, routes

I have made a custom module with layout in magento. its shows customer's information of a particular customer group.

its url is

```
www.mysite.com/profile/index/index/mayank
```

Where profile is my modulename, index is controller name, 2nd index is index controller's method and mayank is customer's username (a unique field or attribute).

What i need is.

Make this url like this:-

```
 www.mysite.com/mayank
```

Comment: by defaul, you cannot do that. but If you replace your modulename with `myank`, you can achieve it easily

Comment: Please rethink the shorter URL.  A customer could register the username "admin" or any other module name and instantly break your store.

Comment: @clockworkgeek you are right. Is there anyway we can do like 'if no route found then magento calls our module's controller as it now shows 404 page.'? I'm not expert in magento. i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Magento URLs tend to put the field name before the value.  So I expect the long URL to actually look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/profile/index/index/name/mayank
```

This would allow for a neat retrieval in the controller,

```
public function indexAction() {
    $name = $this->getRequest()->get('name');
}
```

---

> “Is there anyway we can do like 'if no route found then magento calls our module's controller..?”

I've [wrestled with routers before](https://github.com/Knectar/Magento-Store-Codes) and in my opinion they are unnecessary unless absolutely necessary.  When the number of possible URLs is finite then it is easier to [save a rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4927988/471559) in advance.  The best time to do this is whenever a username changes.

To listen for a change add this to your module's `config.xml`:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <mayank_profile>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mayank_profile/observer</class>
                    <method>customerSaveAfter</method>
                </mayank_profile>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
        <customer_delete_after>
            <observers>
                <mayank_profile>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mayank_profile/observer</class>
                    <method>customerDeleteAfter</method>
                </mayank_profile>
            </observers>
        </customer_delete_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

In your module's `Model` folder create `Observer.php`:

```
class Mayank_Profile_Model_Observer {
    public function customerSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        // username is not a standard attribute, hopefully you have created it
        if ($customer->dataHasChangedFor('username')) {
            $this->remove($customer->getOrigData('username'));
            $this->add($customer->getData('username'));
        }
    }

    public function customerDeleteAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $this->remove($customer->getOrigData('username'));
    }

    protected function remove($username) {
        // this does nothing if rewrite doesn't exist
        Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
            ->loadByIdPath('profile/'.$username);
            ->delete();
    }

    protected function add($username) {
        if ($this->isValidUsername($username)) {
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView()->getId();

            Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setIsSystem(0)
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                // IdPath is used by remove() function
                ->setIdPath('profile/'.$username)
                // TargetPath is your controller/action
                ->setTargetPath('profile/index/index/name/'.$username)
                // RequestPath is what the browser sees
                ->setRequestPath($username)
                ->save();
        }
    }

    protected function isValidUsername($username) {
        // feel free to add more checks here
        // start with existing rewrites
        $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
            ->loadByRequestPath($username);
        if (!$rewrite->isObjectNew()) {
            return false;
        }

        // scan known frontNames
        $frontNames = Mage::getConfig()->getXPath('*/routers/*/args/frontName');
        foreach ($frontNames as $name) {
            if ($username == (string) $name) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It's quite a bit of work but the advantage here is the following code correctly looks up the path earlier saved as "RequestPath":

```
echo Mage::getUrl('profile', array(
    'name' => $username,
    '_use_rewrite' => true
));
```

---

Here is a much simpler way which only works for URLs that cannot clash with other modules.  Add this to your `config.xml`:

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <mayank_profile>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/profile/#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/profile/index/index/name/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </mayank_profile>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

When outputting an URL you need to concatenate the path yourself. e.g.

```
echo Mage::getUrl('', array(
    // Use _direct here to avoid a trailing solidus
    '_direct' => 'profile/' . $username
));
```

Comment: Its right answer But looks like i need to black list all admin,customer or product name and so on from using as username. So i should better convince my client to use as www.sitename.com/profile/username. Am i right?

Comment: I hoped the `isValidUsername()` function would cover most of the black list, although I have not tested it.  There is no guarantee if will successfully block all future, legitimate URLs.  For example I just realised it does not consider CMS pages.  I've updated my answer to handle the `www.sitename.com/profile/username` format.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to return error message from observer when invalid username using setFlag method with 'FLAG_NO_DISPATCH' but i'm unable to get object of controller. can you help me?

Comment: That's a separate problem.  Start a new question and explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve this with a `htaccess rewriterule`

Or

create an observer on `controller_action_layout_load_before` and fetch the `REQUEST_URI` and use it for your case.

Good luck

Comment: If you can tell me in detail about solving this using observer than it will be good. I'm a beginner in magento.