# Htaccess redirect with subdirectories and dynamic querystring

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have a Magento site installed in subfolder like `http-host/subdir1/subdir2/siterootdir`.

Now I want to shorten a rather long URL of my brands page like below:

Request URL:

`http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/siterootdir/brands/brandname.html`

to

Original URL:

`http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/siterootdir/brands/index/brandsproduct/brand/brandname`

with `htaccess` redirects with dynamic querystring.

I have tried many examples from google searching, but I keep getting `404 not found` page when I run my required request URL (as above).

Also I am not so good at regex & rewrite rules/conditions, so can anybody provide solution for above issue & also explain details behind it?

Note that *brandname* is dynamic, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach for solving these, as I needed to rewrite only brands specific urls, so it wasn't entirely related to htaccess scenario I guess, so I changed approach little bit & did [rewrite programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900135/magento-rewrites-for-deeply-nested-category-pages) into Core URL Rewrites("custom" type) whenever any brand was saved from admin, also I didn't want the urls into browser to change, which is provided by magento into URL Rewrites.

Even though if somebody finds solution the "htaccess" way then let me know, I am still open for that, as I won't have to save every brand for creating it's url rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess file will redirect `http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/siterootdir/brands/brandname.html` to `http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/siterootdir/brands/index/brandsproduct/brand/brandname`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} hostname$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !index
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/siterootdir/brands/index/brandsproduct/brand/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Put this at the `http://hostname/subdir1/subdir2/siterootdir/brands/` location

The `\.html` strips the html extention from the URL.

The `R=302` marks the redirect as temporary. Use 301 for Moved Permanently.

Comment: As I said earlier it is a magento site, and there is no directory like "brands" in it, it is just in the url. I have site installed at "siterootdir" directory, so can you edit your answer so that I can put it in root folder htaccess file ?

Comment: So in the request URL you have two variables: 'brands' and 'brandname'. These can be used in the rewite rule. However where does 'brandsproduct' come from?