# How to short the url controller in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a controller named «wizard» that should get a parameter and then, depending on this parameter, do this thing or another thing.

I can do this easily with the url http://mysite.com/wizard/index/index/action/cutting. That should give the action parameter with the value «cutting» to my indexAction of my IndexController.

But what I'd really want is to have the same thing but with the url: 
http://mysite.com/wizard/cutting

Where «cutting» is the parameter. If I want to handle this with my indexAction of my IndexController.php, what should I change on the config.xml? (well, I'm supposing that I can set this on the config.xml file, but don't know how).

Btw: I know I can pass something like ?action=cutting, but that's not what I want...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable `mod_rewrite` on your server (if you are using apache) and enable `"Use web server rewrites"`

[Here's a good tutorial](http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento) explaining the issues.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, Anton. But the thing is that the parameter is dynamic. Depending on that parameter, a different wizard will be executed. The number of wizards is undefined, so I can't set them up on the url rewrites section. I need to avoid the index/index/action part (well, if I can't do that, that long url can work for me, but I'd prefer a shorter url).

Comment: this does not matter if you need to get rid of /index/index/action/ then mod rewrite must be enabled

Comment: OK, I see. But I wanted to add this rule directly from my module. I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768681/url-rewriting-for-magento-module (your answer gave me the clue to know what to look exactly for ;) )

Comment: this is built in to magento and all you have to do is to enable it form backend and make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: Well, in this case I wanted to define the rewrite rule in my config.xml. So the solution was adding a <rewrite> - from - to directly.